# (C#) AccessViolationException when getting char ** from C++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, dll, interop, access-violation

I've written a basic C++ library that gets data from an OPC UA server and formats it into an array of strings (char **). I've confirmed that it works standalone, but now I'm trying to call it from a C# program using DLLs/pInvoke and running into serious memory errors.

My C# main:

```
List<String> resultList = new List<string>();
IntPtr inArr = new IntPtr();
inArr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(inArr);
resultList = Utilities.ReturnStringArray(/*data*/,inArr);
```

C# Helper functions:

```
public class Utilities{

    [DllImport(//DllArgs- confirmed to be correct)]
    private static extern void getTopLevelNodes(/*data*/, IntPtr inArr);

    public static List<String> ReturnStringArray(/*data*/,IntPtr inArr)
    {

       getTopLevelNodes(/*data*/,inArr); // <- this is where the AccessViolationException is thrown
       //functions that convert char ** to List<String>
       //return list
    }
```

And finally, my C++ DLL implementation:

```
extern "C" EXPORT void getTopLevelNodes(*/data*/,char **ret){

std::vector<std::string> results = std::vector<std::string>();
//code that fills vector with strings from server

ret = (char **)realloc(ret, sizeof(char *));
ret[0] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
strcpy(ret[0], "");
int count = 0;
int capacity = 1;

for (auto string : results){
        ret[count] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 2048);
        strcpy(ret[count++], string.c_str());
        if (count == capacity){
                capacity *= 2;
                ret = (char **)realloc(ret, sizeof(char *)*capacity + 1);
        }
}
```

What this should do is, initialize a List to hold the final result and IntPtr to be populated as a char ** by the C++ DLL, which is then processed back in C# and formatted into a List. However, an AccessViolationException is thrown every time I call getTopLevelNodes from C#. What can I do to fix this memory issue? Is this the best way to pass an array of strings via interop?

Thank you in advance

**Edit:**
I'm still looking for more answers, if there's a simpler way to implement string array interop between C# and a DLL, please, let me know!

Comment: Not putting this as an answer as I am unsure and unable to test it, but have you tried using `IntPtr[]` instead of `IntPtr` since you are, in a sense, passing an array of pointers, not just a single pointer.  Also, just as a side note, I believe you have a memory leak of 1 char for your first array element, since you malloc a spot for it, then call malloc again on the first iteration of your loop.

Comment: @pstrjds thanks, I'll fix it

Comment: I don't know your situation, but would it be possible to create a C++/CLI wrapper around your C++ call?  Then you could have a class that makes the call that fills the vector, but then push that data into a .Net structure for consumption on your C# side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**METHOD 1 - Advanced Struct Marshalling.**

As opposed to marshalling a list, try creating a c# struct like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 2)]
public struct StringData
{
    public string [] mylist; /* maybe better yet byte[][] (never tried)*/
};
```

Now in c# marshall like this:

```
IntPtr pnt = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(StringData)); // Into Unmanaged space
```

Get A pointer to the structure.

```
StringData theStringData = /*get the data*/;
Marshal.StructureToPtr(theStringData, pnt, false);
                                    // Place structure into unmanaged space.

getTopLevelNodes(/* data */, pnt); // call dll

theStringData =(StringData)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pnt,typeof(StringData));
                                    //get structure back from unmanaged space.
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pnt); // Free shared mem
```

Now in CPP:

```
#pragma pack(2)
/************CPP STRUCT**************/
struct StringDataCpp
{
    char * strings[]
};
```

And the function:

```
extern "C" EXPORT void getTopLevelNodes(/*data*/,char *ret){ //just a byte pointer.   

struct StringDataCpp *m = reinterpret_cast<struct StringDataCpp*>(ret);

//..do ur thing ..//

}
```

I have used this pattern with much more complicated structs as well. The key is that you're just copying byte by byte from c# and interpreting byte by byte in c++.

The 'pack' is key here, to ensure the structs align the same way in memory.

**METHOD 2 - Simple byte array with `fixed`**

```
    //USE YOUR LIST EXCEPT List<byte>. 
        unsafe{
           fixed (byte* cp = theStringData.ToArray)
             {

                getTopLevelNodes(/* data */, cp)
    /////...../////

//SNIPPET TO CONVERT STRING ARRAY TO BYTE ARRAY
    string[] stringlist = (/* get your strings*/);
    byte[] theStringData = new stringlist [stringlist .Count()];
     foreach (string b in parser)
     {
// ADD SOME DELIMITER HERE FOR CPP TO SPLIT ON?
          theStringData [i] = Convert.ToByte(stringlist [i]);
          i++;
     }
```

NOW

CPP just receives char*. You'll need a delimiter now to seperate the strings.
NOTE THAT YOUR STRING PROBABLY HAS DELIMETER '\0' ALREADY USE A REPLACE ALGORITHM TO REPLACE THAT WITH a ';' OR SOMETHING AND TOKENIZE EASILY IN A LOOP IN CPP USING STRTOK WITH ';' AS THE DELIMITER OR USE BOOST!

OR, try making a byte pointer array if possible.

```
Byte*[i] theStringStartPointers = &stringList[i]/* in a for loop*/
fixed(byte* *cp = theStringStartPointers) /// Continue
```

This way is much simpler. The `unsafe` block allows the `fixed` block and the fixed ensures that the c# memory management mechanism does not move that data.

Comment: This looks promising, I'll try to implement and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: @T.Meads Since these are strings make sure you notice my edit, you must Marshal.sizeof(theStringData) since it is at runtime that the string sizes will be determined!. Ideally the structs would be deterministic sized. ie a certain number of byte arrays of a certain size. byte[5][12].

Comment: @T.Meads matter of fact since you just use strings I like my "method 2" that I added better for you.

Comment: The problem is my program handles a large amount of data with up to thousands of strings at a time. I don't think putting it all in one big delimited char * string would be good, memory management wise

Comment: Hmm okay I'll leave all of this as just possible tools you may be able to use , so here's one more thought. Just realize that one IntPtr points to a HGlobal (unmanaged heap global) from there cpp is going to have to interpret where to split this memory into seperate strings. You might need to pass in an array of IntPtrs each of which is a reference to one of the strings. Or fix a byte* cp = anArrayOfBytePointers; Then in cpp reinterpret that to an array of seperate char* which can also be used to construct std::strings